# example just slightly better than the greedy construction

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, peano-arithmetic

Roth's theorem provides an estimate for  the largest
size of a nonaveraging subset of $\lbrace 1,2, \ldots ,n \rbrace$ (a set of integers is nonaveraging if it does not contain any nontrivial three-term arithmetic progression).

If we try to construct such a nonaveraging subset "naively" and "greedily", we obtain
a Cantor subset (the integers $n$ such that the ternary expansion of $n-1$ does not contain a 2), whose
density in $\lbrace 1,2, ... ,n \rbrace$ is $\frac{1}{n^{1-\frac{\log(3)}{log(2)}}}$. This is known to be far from optimal, since Behrend's construction (based on projecting a sphere onto
the interval $[1(...)n]$) yields a set of density around $\frac{1}{2^{\sqrt{8\log_2(n)}}}$ (Elkin improved this, but this is not our concern here ; see http://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/pushing-behrend-around/). Behrend's construction is non-explicit
in that it uses the pigeonhole principle, ans states that some radius provides us a sphere having enough points.

Since the gap between the two is huge, one may ask if there is a more "effective"
construction explaining why the greedy algorithm does not produce an optimal  result,
in the following sense :

Let us denote by $C$ the set of all integers such that the ternary expansion of $n-1$ does not contain a 2, so that the greedy algorithm produces $C \cap \lbrace 1,2, \ldots ,n \rbrace$. Now, is
there  an infinite nonaveraging subset $T$ of $\mathbb N$, such that  $|C \cap \lbrace 1,2, \ldots ,n \rbrace | < |T \cap \lbrace 1,2, \ldots ,n \rbrace |$ for all large enough $n$ ?

Update 02/01/2001 : to avoid "parasitic" and non-explicit examples as explained in fedja's comments, one may impose the additional hard requirement that $T$ is constructed by first imposing a condition of the form $T \cap X_0=Y_0$ where $X_0$ is a finite set and then filling $T$ greedily.

Comment: The formal answer is "Yes, of course: just do Behrend's construction on intervals $5^k,2\cdot 5^k$ and skip the rest". You certainly meant something more interesting than that, but I am at loss as to how to state the question to eliminate such "parasitic answers". The word "elementary" might be the key but what is so non-elementary about projecting a sphere?

Comment: Perhaps the right question asks how high the density can get as a function of how often we have the option to skip the greedy choice? 

Comment:   @fedja : it is obvious that we may construct an infinite set that does better than the Cantor set for infinitely many $n$. It is not clear to me, however, that it will be better for all large enough $n$.  In other words, the miscellaneous spheres we will obtain for a fast-growing sequence (say, the powers of 5) do not have to form a "coherent whole".  

Comment: -----It is not clear to me, however, that it will be better for all large enough $n$----  What do you mean? You have power on full $\mathbb N$ versus subpower on a set of positive lower density. The latter wins for all large $n$ hands down. I agree that it is not very explicit though. 

Comment: I am likely to miss something very basic, but why "if we  try to construct such a nonaveraging subset "naively" and "greedily", we obtain a Cantor subset (the integers whose ternary expansion does not contain a 1)"? If we start with $1$, then we already have the "non-Cantor" element $1$ in our set. If you start with $2$, then, to continue greedily, you have to include $3$, which is a non-Cantor number again, etc.

Comment: I like this problem although I do not understand what precisely is the problem. (Of course there are various other not as good construction that were discovered before Behrend.) It is interesting to compare the greedy algorithm with a random construction (if the size is < n^{1/3} the expected number of 3-term AP is <1). We can also consider "large deviation heuristic" which predicts that if (1-p^3)^{n^2} (n choose pn) >>1 there is a set of size pn without 3-term AP. This will suggest another exponent. (but very far from the constructions).   

Comment: I suppose that by greedily you take 1,2,...,n in this order one by one and delete an element that creates an AP. Perhaps you can do better by taking them in some other (natural) order.

Comment: @ Seva : you're right, my initial statement was incorrect : the exact formulation is "C is the set of integers n such that the ternary expansion of n-1 contains no 2". I edited the OP accordingly

Comment: @ Gil : indeed, one may want to take an unusual order on 1,2, ... ,n, for example beginning by deleting the most central elements (because they are more likely to cause trouble later).